# How to make a get request mid application

Tags: google-app-engine, go

How would I go about creating a GET HTTP request mid application in GAE? I don't want to have it as a handler function, I simply have a URL that I need to get the response body from.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [urlfetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference) package.

```
ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)   // r is the *http.Request arg to the handler
client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)  
resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com")
if err != nil {
    // handle the error 
}
body := resp.Body // body is an io.Reader containing the response body
```

[Here's a complete example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/docs/appengine/urlfetch/urlfetch.go).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it so apologies if this doesn't work. According to [GAE's docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/reference#Client) you probably want to use `urlfetch` to get a `*http.Client` something like (N.B. the `context` package is standard in the just released Go 1.7):

```
import (
    "context" // Go 1.7
    // "golang.org/x/net/context" // Go < 1.7
    "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
)

client := urlfetch.Client(context.Background())
resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com/")
```